# Options from SELECT menu is hiding

Tags: jquery, menu, html-select, prepend

I am trying to 'prependTo' "SELECT menu" to DIVs. Menu is 'prependingTo' on 'mouseover' over DIVs. In this menu is the SELECT with some options.
But when I want choose some other option, options from SELECT menu is hidding. It does not work. Why ?

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/ynternet/8MSnh/)

***HTML:***

```
 <div id="add" style='width:200px; background:cyan;'> + + + + + + + + + </div>
 <div id="menu">
     <div style="display:inline-block;">
         <button>1</button>
         <button>2</button>
     </div>
     <div style="display:inline-block;">
         <select id="fs">
            <option value="Arial">Arial</option>
            <option value="Verdana ">Verdana </option>
            <option value="Impact ">Impact </option>
            <option value="Comic Sans MS">Comic Sans MS</option>
         </select>
     </div>

 </div>
 <br>
 <div id="cont">
    <div id="container">
       <div id="divA">1111<br><br>&nbsp;</div>
       <br>
       <div id="divB">2222<br><br>&nbsp;</div>
       <br>
       <div id="divC">33333<br><br>&nbsp;</div>
       <br>
       <div id="divD"><br>&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

***CSS:***

```css
  #container{ padding: 100px;  }
  #menu{  font-size: 10px;  
       position: absolute;
       background-color: none;
       letter-spacing: 0px;
  }
  #divA{ background-color: yellow; }
  #divB{ background-color: red;  }
  .divB{ background-color: red; }
  #divC{ background-color: cyan; }
  #divD{ background-color: brown; }
```

***jQuery:***

```
  $("#add").live("click", function() {
     var timestamp = Date.now();
     $("#container").prepend('<div class="divB" id="'+timestamp+'">'+timestamp+'<br><br></div>');
  });
  $("#container div").live({
     mouseover: function() {
        if( $(this).closest("#menu").length ){ return; }
        $('#menu').prependTo($(this));
     }
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
$("#container").bind({
    mouseover: function() {
        if( $(this).closest("#menu").length ){ 
            return; 
        }
        $('#menu').prependTo(this);
        $("#container").unbind('mouseover');       
    }
});
```

Comment: thank you for helping me, but I updated my code and example. There are some dynamically added DIVs. Your solution work for ones. Then script stops.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `find` method instead of `closest`, `closest` selects the closest parent of the element and you want to find the descendant of the element, your if statement always returns `false`, also note that `live` is deprecated, you can use `on` instead.

```
$(document).on({
        mouseover: function(e) {
            if( $(this).find("#menu").length ){ return; }
            // or if ( $('#menu', this).length ){ return; }
            $('#menu').prependTo($(this));

        }
}, "#container div");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/h7y3Z/

Comment: Thank you. This one is working fine. In this case is "onclick" better than "live" ?

Comment: @Patrik Yes, `on` is too much better than `live` if you want to delegate the events, also `live` is deprecated and in future versions of jQuery it will be removed from the API.

Comment: but, when I insert dynamicaly another DIVs in menu, "onclick" does not work.... :( 

http://jsfiddle.net/ynternet/h7y3Z/1/

Comment: @Patrik You are not binding click , you are binding on mouseover and it works http://jsfiddle.net/UYvMZ/

Comment: Sorry for my english... you are right, but... When new DIVs are dynamically added to the "#container", mouseover function does not work on this new DIVs. So I must to use "live", becouse I need dynamically add new DIVs to the "#container". 
But there is still problem with hiddin SELECT. :-[

Comment: @Patrik Okay, I see, if you want to delegate the event using `on` method, you should delegate the event from one of static parents of the element or document object, try the updated code.